# Updating specific subdocuments in MongoDB :

Tags: mongodb

In my MongoDB, I have Document, as seen below.
How To Update document inside inner document structures look like: `[{1},[{2}],[{3}],[{4}]]`.

Ex : Child document inside subchild document have `objectId:1` and `objectId:2` and `objectId:3` and `objectId:4`.
Like:

```
[{ _id : ObjectId("1")}],
[{ _id : ObjectId("2")}], 
[{ _id : ObjectId("3")}],
[{ _id : ObjectId("4")}]


"Child": [{
    "_id": ObjectId("1"),
     Name: "Raghu",
     Age : 21,

    "subchild": [{
            "_id": ObjectId("2"),
            "Name": "Yuva",
             Age : 23,
        },
        [{
                "_id": ObjectId("3"),
                 Name: "Ravi",
                 Age : 25
            }
        ],
        [{
                 "_id": ObjectId("4"),
                "Name": "Ram",
                  Age : 27
            }
        ]
    ],
}
```

]

How to update above following subchild document Specific _Id: ObjectId("3") and  _Id : ObjectId("4") 
Ex:  [{ "_id": ObjectId("4"), "Name": "Ram", } ]

I'm tried in C# like this  :

```
          I updated ObjectId : 1 like  Example   child.$.Subchild.0.Name="Raghu" 
        But not Updated ObjectId : 4 like  Example   child.$.Subchild.3.Name="Ram"           

    MongoServerSettings settings = new MongoServerSettings();
        settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("127.1.1.1", 27017);
        MongoServer servers = new MongoServer(settings);
        var db = servers.GetDatabase("StudentDB");
        MongoCollection<Student> pax;
        pax = db.GetCollection<Student>("StudentDetails");
        IMongoQuery queryEdit = Query.EQ("Child.subchild._id", new ObjectId("4"));
        var updateValues = new List<UpdateBuilder>();
        { updateValues.Add(Update.Set("child.$.Subchild.3.Name", "Ramu")); }
        updateValues.Add(Update.Set("child.$.subchild.3.Age", 27));
        IMongoUpdate update = Update.Combine(updateValues);  
        SafeModeResult sm = pax.Update(queryEdit, update, UpdateFlags.None, SafeMode.True);
```

Answer (score 0):

`child.$.Subchild.0.Name="Raghu"` don't need the references to first array cursor, need the references for the second cursor `child.Subchild.$.Name="Raghu"` for MongodDB don't update whit two references "$"

```
db.foo.update({_id:ObjectId(...),"child.Subchild.Name":"Ram"},{$set:{child.Subchild.$.Name="Raghu"}});
```